# Shift allocated memory

Tags: c, realloc

I have this code:

```
int items = 2;
int *array = malloc(items * sizeof(int));
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
```

I want to pop first item and shift allocated memory just from the left side to do:

```
array[0] == 2
```

Probably need to get address of array and shift it for *`poped_items * sizeof(int)`* or something like this? What should be the first realloc argument?

Comment: why `==`? That's for comparisons in `if/else` statements.

Comment: _Probably need to get address of array and shift it for poped_items * sizeof(int) or something like this?_  Yes, more or less, you need to shift the rest of the array downwards and then simply call `array = realloc(array, thenewsize)`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: you mean `array = realloc(array+1,sizeof(int))`. But the new `array` value cannot be the old value + 1.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre no not at all, read the realloc man  page.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : Anyways the realloc demands another pointer for its result. Plus you've memory leak in that realloc?

Comment: you cannot pass `array+1` to `realloc` I was wrong. So basically you have to allocate another memory zone, memcpy and free. Shifting is not possible.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre shifting is possible, but you need to write the code to shift the elements, or better use `memmove`.

Comment: I see: shift and realloc afterwards to shorten the size.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove items on the left (and simply working with `&array[ItemsToShift]` instead of a plain `array` isn't enough), don't `realloc`, just `memmove`:

```
memmove(&array[0], &array[1], (items-(&array[1]-array[0]))*sizeof(int));
```

If you want, you can make it a type generic macro:

```
#define DARRAY_shift(Array, Size, Nshift) \
    memmove(&array[0], \
            &array[Nshift], \
            (Size-(&array[Nshift]-&array[0]))*sizeof(Array[0]) \
           );
```

You could `realloc` after the `memmove`:

```
new_array = realloc(array, (Size-Nshift)*sizeof(array[0]));
```

but that's potentially a waste of cycles as you can just ignore the gap at the end of your dynamic array created by the shift.

Comment: forget & operator in first code, it looks it's working

Comment: @Vospala It can be expressed in a couple of different ways. I wasn't trying to use as few characters as possible.